# rand() seeded the same way generates different results

Tags: php, c++, c, random, srand

I am developing an application in PHP and C but the result of `rand` is different between the two languages, even though I am using the same seed:

PHP:

```
srand(1);
$random = rand(); // returns 32422
```

C:

```
srand(1);
int random = rand(); // returns 41
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: So they use different generators. That's not very surprising.

Comment: Wow! Fascinating! Pseudo-random number generators return different results! (Nothing in the PHP documents states that `rand()` (PHP) uses `rand()` (C). Even then, you don't know whether both use the same seed).

Comment: thats why they are called random. Both might be using different pseudo random algos

Comment: Yes it is. Why do you expect them to be the same? Is there anywhere in the PHP specs that PHP's `rand()` should behave exactly the same way as C's one?

Comment: who told you they should generate same output?

Comment: my apple is not like my orange, why?

Comment: The question isn't as bad as it looks like at first glance, but it's still pretty bad. It still boils down to the basic answer that PHP and C use a different PRNG. You could have them return the same thing if you made them use the same PRNG. One possible way to do that would be to use a common library, like OpenSSL.

Comment: @NullUserException: Wy is "it pretty bad" !!! If it boils down to a single answer then it is a perfect question for SO (there is no ambiguity) and thus a real question. I just voted to re-open. This happens a lot. Having an answer here on SO would definitely be us-full to other people (as the frequency this happens is high). Though we should edit it to be more language agnostic (so people can find it easily).

Comment: Just as a further data point, you can also get different results for different C implementations.

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one way to implement a pseudo-random number generator.

Every programming language is free to specify its own `rand` implementation, or even to specify nothing. For example, the C specification only says that "The `rand` function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to `RAND_MAX`." There's no mention of how `rand` should work, so the compiler writers can implement `rand` however they like.

Many compilers use a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) to implement `rand`. Even this simple algorithm has parameters that the compiler is free to specify, and which changes the sequence of numbers given by a particular seed.

[image: LCG parameters]

Look how Borland and glibc use different parameters. You can't even trust `rand` to work the same across all C programs, let alone all programs in general!